# Error while trying to use `sforce.apex.execute`

Tags: javascript

I was trying to use the `sforce.apex.execute` in javascript using

```
<script src="/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i got the following error in connection.js

```
uncaught exception: {faultcode:'sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID', faultstring:'INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session', }
```

How can i overcome this error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sometimes the session ID isn't set correctly, so you have to set it yourself.

```
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
```

**Updated**: Here's an example usage.

```
<apex:page >
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/28.0/apex.js"/>
<script>
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
function doAnon() {
    sforce.apex.executeAnonymous(document.getElementById("input").value, anonResult);
}
function anonResult(result) {
    alert(result);
}
</script>
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<button onclick="doAnon()">Execute</button>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: where should i exactly call this code

Comment: why am i getting this error while implementing your code `'sforce' is undefined `

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a code example.

Comment: receiving errors `Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent" `

Comment: 1. Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent" 
2. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Server Error) https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/services/Soap/u/27.0
3. Uncaught {faultcode:'sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID', faultstring:'INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session', detail:{UnexpectedErrorFault:{exceptionCode:'INVALID_SESSION_ID', exceptionMessage:'Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session', }, }, }

Comment: The first "error" isn't a problem. It's just a header that doesn't get set. The second/third errors are related. You're obviously either not setting the ID correctly or it's getting mangled somewhere. Did you try starting from my code on this answer? It works verbatim in my developer edition. Try looking at the generated HTML for your page and make sure that a line that looks like sforce.connection.sessionId = ... exists and has a valid session ID. I think we might need to see more code to help you.

Comment: i made an alert in the script : ` alert(sforce.connection.sessionId);` this returned null

Comment: i have to get the profile name from te apex class controller to a html are custom component , in there im getting these problem

Comment: Are you referring to a custom home page component? You can't easily get the session ID from there, so you'll have to write a Visualforce page that will output your JavaScript code so you can get the session ID.