# How to execute the standard Onclick Javascript code from Detail Page Button in a Visualforce Page?

Tags: javascript, metadata-api, html5, detail-page, onclick

I've a custom button in the detail view of the object (type is onClick Javascript). I have a visualforce Page where I'm trying to replicate the same functionality done through the Onclick JS button in the page.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}
var result = 'www.google.com';
window.top.location.href = result;
```

I was wondering if the button code can be brought in to execute the code. Metadata API was the approach I chose. I queried the button details through Metadata and I got the simple JS working. However, when I have buttons that use `connection.js` & `apex.js`, BOOM! They don't work.

I replaced the merge fields those used in the JS script to be replaced with the actual value using a Util class. How do I get the `{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}` scripts to work in the page as well?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After including the scripts manually, I faced the same issue mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14217/error-while-trying-to-use-sforce-apex-execute).

Setting __sfdcSessionId did not help since the session Id was not set.

```
var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
```

I had to set the sforce session Id manually.

```
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling from a VF page then the code remains same but ensure that you have added scripts to the top of VF page as below:

```
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js"/>
```

Comment: Amit, I've tried that already. The Session ID is missing and hence I get an error. I don't want to do it manually in JS as well.

Comment: are you passing sessionID somehow ?

Comment: Yes, setting it in JS. var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';

Comment: It may not work. Its always important to generate session ID in context of VF page or batch apex by possibly using a login call. Just read through the last part of my blog post : https://cloudyaffair.wordpress.com/2015/07/22/bulk-scheduling-dashboard-refresh/

Comment: Did it help ? Were you able to work this out ?

Comment: Nope. Still getting the Invalid Session ID error. Will try once again in a new environment and let you know(this one was a managed package dev org I was testing). And yeah, I included 'Package__ /' prefix for the webservice call out in this org.