# Get user id from Javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, salesforce1-app, sforce

I am looking to get the users record type from a certain permission set.  I need to first get the userId and then I have a picklist on the user field which can be used to communicate with a crosswalk table to link to the record type.

I have a feeling I'm supposed to use $user but I keep getting errors.  Also, program__c is a picklist so I'm not sure if that returns a string.

```
<script src="/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js"></script>

<script src="/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {

        var query1 = sforce.connection.query(select program__c from user where id =: $user.userid);
        var query1Result = query1.getArray("records");

        var query2 = sforce.connection.query(select Program_record_type__c from  Fields_to_Program__c where program__c = query1Result[0].program__c);

        var query2Result = query2.getArray("records");

        sforce.one.createRecord('Activity__c', query2Result[0]);

        if(typeof sforce != 'undefined' && sforce != null) {
            sforce.one.createRecord('Activity__c', query2Result[0]);
        } else {
            window.open('/a01/e', '_self');
        }

    }, 3);
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use "bind expressions" in JavaScript. You have to actually use normal strings. This should be approximately correct:

```
setTimeout(function() {

    var query1 = sforce.connection.query("select program__c from user where id = '{!$user.userid}'");
    var query1Result = query1.getArray("records");
    var query2 = sforce.connection.query("select Program_record_type__c from  Fields_to_Program__c where program__c = '"+query1Result[0].program__c+"'");
    var query2Result = query2.getArray("records");
    sforce.one.createRecord('Activity__c', query2Result[0]);
    if(typeof sforce != 'undefined' && sforce != null) {
        sforce.one.createRecord('Activity__c', query2Result[0]);
    } else {
        window.open('/a01/e', '_self');
    }
}, 3);
```

You should note that JavaScript is also case sensitive, so make sure your field names, when referenced in JavaScript, are exactly correct.

Comment: I'm getting this error in the debugger.  Also I needed to change {!$user.userid} to {!user.id} to not get an error:  `faultcode:'sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID', faultstring:'INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session', detail:{UnexpectedErrorFault:{exceptionCode:'INVALID_SESSION_ID', exceptionMessage:'Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session', }, }, }`

Comment: @tjcinnamon See [this answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87699/how-to-execute-the-standard-onclick-javascript-code-from-detail-page-button-in-a/87828#87828) to solve INVALID_SESSION_ID.

Comment: very close now.  Looks like I can't pass a var to sforce.one.createRecord(EntityName[,record type id]).  Do I need to cast as a string?  `Cannot read property 'createRecord' of undefined`

Comment: @tjcinnamon sforce.one is for Salesforce1. If you're not using it, then you can use sforce.connection.create instead. It accepts a single parameter, an array, that contains sobjects. See [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm) for specific examples.

Comment: I am using it for salesforce1 but I was unsure how to debug it on the phone.  (I think it works on Lightning Experience.  So here's the debacle.  From my admin account it will open the edit record to the proper record type.  However, from my test user account, it will not navigate to the edit page of that record type

Comment: should I close this and start another question?

Comment: @tjcinnamon Probably. It'd help to see where you're stuck.

Comment: Solved it.  That permission set needed to have access to the Fields_to_Program__c object and the RecordType__c field!  Classic!  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: @tjcinnamon No problem. Glad you got it!